# CI not booting except in the case of 404 responses

Tags: codeigniter

I’m up against a very strange issue and am hoping someone will have an idea of what is going wrong here.

I have multiple local CI projects running on a local ubuntu machine, normal lamp stack - they are all fine.

I recently took an svn checkout of a project that I have worked on happily before and cannot see any controller/method even though I get http 200 responses for the request.

If I var_dump $this from a method - I get the name of the controller class - not the CI global object.

If I put in a non-existent path - I get the CI 404 page.

Permissions and apache virtual host settings are good. BASEURL is set correctly.

.htaccess and index.php are working as index.php has been removed from the url and I still can dump strings and natural php functions (like class_exists() etc. ) from a correctly routed controller/method combination. However as soon as the server reaches code that requires CI (such as $this->load->helper() etc. ) processing stops.

I have one small lead - the project that I have checked out works fine for multiple developers where I work. I had to recently rebuild my machine to be native ubuntu 12.04 which before was a wubi virtual box (which died).

In order to var_dump from a controller/method request I had to add a __construct() method to the controller in question in order to be routed to the requested method, otherwise I just get an http 200 response but no var_dump.

The native welcome controller (which still exists in our dev checkout) works in exactly the same manner - in order to var_dump I have to add a __construct() method.

If I add parent::__construct() to the method (in either controller), var_dump no longer works.

My new version of php is 5.3.10-1 with Suhosin v0.9.33. The CI version of the checkout is 2.1.0

So essentially CI is not booting except in the case of a 404. Is there something obvious that anyone can see that I have overlooked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you move from CI 1.7 to 2.1 by any chance?  I so I'd check to make sure that you are extending CI_Controller or CI_Model as that's a fairly large change and if I remember correctly the pages will show blank with no error.

Comment: what happens when you enable logs?  I think I've ran into this as well and it usually ends up being something small. I'd put a die statement at the top of your controller and see if it loads and then step through.  Only thing i can think to do at this point.

Comment: Issue was unresolvable with that particular checkout - reinstating backed up files yields different results - so moving on without completely understanding what was going on - I'm voting you up for the logs suggestion as this did help me find a couple of issues. thanks @christian